# How to use ajax send data to controller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new developer in ROR.i use ajax with event change to send data from select_tag in show.html.erb into controller in def show ... end . i try to send data but my script not work.below is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#cbo').change(function() {
       $.ajax({
        url: "/product_details/show",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"cbo_id" : $('#cbo').val()},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
          alert('successfully');
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

in product_details/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(product_detail_path, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= select_tag "categories", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id,     :category_name),:id => 'cbo' %>
<% end %>

def show
  @getcbo = params[:cbo_id]
end
```

I think maybe wrong about url: "/product_details/show" .So how can i use url for send data to def show ... end in controller? .please help me !

Comment: Writing answer for you - lots to change

Comment: can u help me to change? i wanna get answer about my question

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm writing an answer for you lol

Comment: ok,thank you.i'm waiting your answer

Answer (score 28):

Lots of things you need to adjust

---

**MVC**

Firstly, let me explain how ajax calls *should* work in Rails

Because Rails is based around the *[MVC (model view controller) programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)* - you need to build your application around this. The problem for many newbie developers is that it's a little tricky to get your head around this - something which can be learnt relatively simply:

[image]

As you can see, MVC basically puts the "controller" at the center of the party. You must appreciate that in an MVC app, your requests don't go to the "view" first (as many people think) - they go to the *controller*, which builds the relevant data from the *model*, then rendering the *view* for you

So whenever you send a request to your MVC application, you need to remember to base it around your controller actions (not your views)

--

**Ajax**

I don't know how much experience you have with [*ajax* (Asynchronous Javascript and XML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), but in case you don't have much, let me explain.

Ajax is basically just a way to create "pseudo requests" in your browser. By "pseudo request", I mean that it will essentially send another request out of the typical flow of your "normal" application:

[image]

Because [HTTP is "stateless"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) (IE it doesn't persist any settings / "state"), there are no ways to provide "real time" connectivity without something like web sockets.

Ajax provides you with the ability to send & receive data *after* your typical load process has completed, making it appear that you're receiving data in "real time". In reality, you're just sending a pseudo request to your app (always remember that Ajax isn't magic)

---

**Code**

Your code needs to change in several places

--

Firstly, you need to [make your javascript unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (IE remove it from your views & place into your asset piepline)

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "#cbo", function() {
   $.ajax({
   url: "/product_details/show",
   type: "POST",
   data: {"cbo_id" : $(this).val()},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
       alert('successfully');
     }
   });
});

#app/controllers/product_details_controller.rb
Class ProductDetailsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html

   def show
      @product = Product.find params[:id]
      respond_with @product
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to receive back the product JSON object that you've set in the controller, a very basic example.

If you give me some more information about what you'd like to achieve, I'll certainly give you a more refined solution; hopefully the above code demonstrates how the MVC principle works etc

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.but it not yet work.in ajax when i use url :"/product_details/" i can send data into def index...end in controller .but when use url : "/product_details/show" my script not work and can't send data into def show ...end.please help me again

Comment: haha sorry. I got caught up in the explanation taht I forgot the details - /show doesn't exist!

Comment: Can you describe why you want to send the data to the *show action*. `/show` doesn't exist -- it has to be `/product_details/:id` - which takes you to the *show* action (as per MVC)

Comment: because,i do it in show.html.erb, so i must get variable from def show...end.

Comment: What? I can't read your mind - how am I meant to know what you mean?

Comment: Cheeky downvote there - I know the answer is rather broad; you may wish to give me some pointers

Comment: so sorry sir ,now i can send data to def show ... end. but when callback "success: function(data) { $('#demo').html(data)}" it show the whole page of show.html.erb. i wanna get only some path that i want to demo  . how could i do?

Comment: Rich Peck, could you please take a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323316/fullcalendar-passing-js-vars-to-rails-and-vice-versa? It is the extension of this question with nested resources + passing vars from rails to browser. An answer would save my life. Thanks in advance!