# Save a user's pushSubscription info in Rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5, progressive-web-apps

I have followed this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-add-real-web-push-notifications-to-your-web to enable push notifications on my rails app. I am using the webpush gem to send the notifications.

So far, all I have managed to do is get the browser to ask for permission to send notifications, and when I try to call the method send_web_push_notification (shown below) line 2 is throwing up an error.

I think it is because I am not saving the user's pushSubscription info to the database, but I don't know how to do this. In the tutorial, there is this line at the end: 'We use a database JSON field called web_push_subscription to save the pushSubscription info on our users.'

Would someone be able to show me how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**send_web_push_notification method:**

```
def send_web_push_notification(user_id)
    subscription = User.find(user_id).web_push_subscription
    message = {
        title: "You have a message!",
        body: "This is the message body",
        tag: "new-message"
    }
    unless subscription.nil?
        Webpush.payload_send(
            message: JSON.generate(message),
            endpoint: subscription["endpoint"],
            p256dh: subscription["keys"]["p256dh"],
            auth: subscription["keys"]["auth"],
            ttl: 15,
            vapid: {
                subject: 'mailto:admin@example.com',
          public_key: Rails.application.config.webpush_keys[:public_key],
          private_key: Rails.application.config.webpush_keys[:private_key]
        }
        )
     end


    end
```

**serviceworker.js.erb:**

```
    function showNotification(event) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const { body, title, tag } = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
        self.registration
            .getNotifications({ tag })
            .then(existingNotifications => { // close? ignore? })
            .then(() => {
                const icon = `/path/to/icon`;
                return self.registration
                    .showNotification(title, { body, tag, icon })
            })
            .then(resolve)
    })
}
self.addEventListener("push", event => {
 event.waitUntil(
    showNotification(event)
        );
    }
});
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", event => {
    event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow("/"));
});
```

**application.js:**

```
const permission = Notification.requestPermission();
if (permission !== 'granted') {
    // no notifications
}else{
    // yay notifications
}

function subscribeToPushNotifications(registration) {
    return registration.pushManager
        .subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true,
            applicationServerKey: window.vapidPublicKey
        })
        .then(pushSubscription => {
            console.log(
                "Received PushSubscription:",
                JSON.stringify(pushSubscription)
            );
            return pushSubscription;
        });
}
```

Comment: `User.find(user_id).web_push_subscription`
Does your user have `has_one` relation with WebPushSubscription? If not, then try `User.find(user_id).web_push_subscriptions.first` or `User.find(user_id).web_push_subscriptions.find([id])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I haven't been able to save the pushSubscription information to the database, have you got any ideas about how I would do this (how I would save it in the web_push_subscription attribute for each user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely codes you will notice that you have to create a Json field in database to save subscription. If there is subscription available than push notification will be sent. Actually there many more scenarios it is not necessary the you want to save one browser for user notification, if you plan multiple browser than you have to create separate table, but if you want to add one browser for push notification, than you can add this information in user table too. Create new migration to update your user table and add following column

```
t.json "web_push_subscription"
```

Run migration, Now you have Json column if you notice code clearly following are information you require in your user database, you will save this information when user subscribe for push notification

```
user. web_push_subscription[:endpoint] = what_ever_value_received
user.web_push_subscription[:auth] = what_ever_value_received
```

Unfortunately it is just idea as I have not implement it, but I should check JSON.stringify(pushSubscription) object recived, and there are chances all data would be in this response which you received you may need to save it as it is to your subscription.
You also need to save permission, that user really allowed you to send notification, if yes than one field in user as boolean notification = true, so you can check if user allow you to send notification, than you can send, otherwise don't send. You should also have way to remove these keys for specific user when they unsubscribe notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how would I save the data held in the JSON.stringify(pushSubscription) to the Rails database? Can this be done from within my application.js file or does it have to be sent to the ApplicationController in some way?

Comment: It depend how you are getting this information, and where, if it is web view and you are getting you can setup ajax request to update this information. But data most go to action controller or rails to save it than you care implement your logic their.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to update a model, which is backend, but you do not want the user to go through all that process. This is where ajax comes in handy. I am not very comfortable with ajax but it is one of the best things provided by JS.
With the code in ajax function, you will hit the controller update action with the changed attribute and the update will change the model as necessary and update it. then your html will change accordingly without page refresh.

**TLDR:** I think you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459743/how-to-use-ajax-send-data-to-controller-in-ruby-on-rails).